# Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS dual boot problem on restarting

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I had a new Laptop (ASUS G553V) with W10 in OEM install... It has two hard disks:

- SSD 25OGo mount on /dev/sda where is installed W10
- SATA 1To mount on /dev/sdb where is installed Ubuntu 16.04 and the EFI mount on /boot/efi

After more difficulties (espacially cause CD and LiveUsb are not detected by the Bios Boot menu so You must mount a disk image in a dedicated Fat32 partition mount on /dev/sda3 with me), i managed to install Ubuntu 16.04... but The problem is that at restart, the entry "Ubuntu" starts a purple screen and stops.

I just can start Ubunutu on recovery mode :-(

I tried more options:

- disable fast boot
- updgrade the Bios at the newest version
- reinstall grub with BootRepair

  etc ...

But i don't find the solution on my brain and on the web...

This is the newest boot info from boot repair:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24773991/

...the result of fdisk -l:

```
Disque /dev/sda : 238,5 GiB, 256060514304 octets, 500118192 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F29D9901-E36A-4B98-BB5F-6F191A71E76C

Périphérique     Start       Fin  Secteurs   Size Type
/dev/sda1         2048     34815     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2        34816 251228159 251193344 119,8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3    251228160 255422463   4194304     2G Microsoft basic data


Disque /dev/sdb : 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 octets, 1953525168 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 823F2D7D-72CE-4319-A5D7-3BD97C674330

Périphérique      Start        Fin   Secteurs   Size Type
/dev/sdb1          2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2       1050624 1920221183 1919170560 915,1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3    1920221184 1953523711   33302528  15,9G Partition d'échange Linux
```

and the result of lshw :

```
j1v3-gl553vw
    description: Ordinateur Bloc-notes
    produit: GL553VW (ASUS-NotebookSKU)
    fabriquant: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    version: 1.0
    numéro de série: GBN0CV11472846F
    bits: 64 bits
    fonctionnalités: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=GL sku=ASUS-NotebookSKU uuid=2AD205A7-DF61-4A85-97A6-85589D3C95E9
  *-core
       description: Carte mère
       produit: GL553VW
       fabriquant: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       version: 1.0
       numéro de série: BSN12345678901234567
       emplacement: Default string
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          fabriquant: American Megatrends Inc.
          identifiant matériel: 0
          version: 303
          date: 01/26/2017
          taille: 64KiB
          capacité: 15MiB
          fonctionnalités: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          identifiant matériel: 3d
          emplacement: L1 Cache
          taille: 128KiB
          capacité: 128KiB
          fonctionnalités: synchronous internal write-back data
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L1 cache
          identifiant matériel: 3e
          emplacement: L1 Cache
          taille: 128KiB
          capacité: 128KiB
          fonctionnalités: synchronous internal write-back instruction
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:2
          description: L2 cache
          identifiant matériel: 3f
          emplacement: L2 Cache
          taille: 1MiB
          capacité: 1MiB
          fonctionnalités: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:3
          description: L3 cache
          identifiant matériel: 40
          emplacement: L3 Cache
          taille: 6MiB
          capacité: 6MiB
          fonctionnalités: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          produit: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
          fabriquant: Intel Corp.
          identifiant matériel: 41
          information bus: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
          numéro de série: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          emplacement: U3E1
          taille: 859MHz
          capacité: 4005MHz
          bits: 64 bits
          horloge: 100MHz
          fonctionnalités: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
     *-memory
          description: Mémoire Système
          identifiant matériel: 42
          emplacement: Carte mère
          taille: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM Synchrone 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
             produit: M471A1K43BB0-CPB
             fabriquant: Samsung
             identifiant matériel: 0
             numéro de série: 22211783
             emplacement: ChannelA-DIMM0
             taille: 8GiB
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: Project-Id-Version: @(#) $Id$Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2016-06-24 06:52+0000Last-Translator: Lyonel Vincent Language-Team: MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2016-06-27 17:08+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18115)Project-Id-Version: @(#) $Id$Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2016-06-24 06:52+0000Last-Translator: Lyonel Vincent Language-Team: MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2016-06-27 17:08+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18115) [vide]
             identifiant matériel: 1
             emplacement: ChannelA-DIMM1
        *-bank:2
             description: SODIMM Synchrone 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
             produit: M471A1K43BB0-CPB
             fabriquant: Samsung
             identifiant matériel: 2
             numéro de série: 22211789
             emplacement: ChannelB-DIMM0
             taille: 8GiB
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: Project-Id-Version: @(#) $Id$Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2016-06-24 06:52+0000Last-Translator: Lyonel Vincent Language-Team: MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2016-06-27 17:08+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18115)Project-Id-Version: @(#) $Id$Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2016-06-24 06:52+0000Last-Translator: Lyonel Vincent Language-Team: MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2016-06-27 17:08+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18115) [vide]
             identifiant matériel: 3
             emplacement: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          produit: Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          fabriquant: Intel Corporation
          identifiant matériel: 100
          information bus: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          bits: 32 bits
          horloge: 33MHz
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             produit: Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16)
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1
             information bus: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 07
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             ressources: irq:122 portE/S:e000(taille=4096) mémoire:de000000-df0fffff portE/S:c0000000(taille=301989888)
           *-display NON-RÉCLAMÉ
                description: 3D controller
                produit: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
                fabriquant: NVIDIA Corporation
                identifiant matériel: 0
                information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a2
                bits: 64 bits
                horloge: 33MHz
                fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                ressources: mémoire:de000000-deffffff mémoire:c0000000-cfffffff mémoire:d0000000-d1ffffff portE/S:e000(taille=128) mémoire:df000000-df07ffff
        *-display NON-RÉCLAMÉ
             description: VGA compatible controller
             produit: Intel Corporation
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 2
             information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             ressources: mémoire:dd000000-ddffffff mémoire:b0000000-bfffffff portE/S:f000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff
        *-generic:0 NON-RÉCLAMÉ
             description: System peripheral
             produit: Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 8
             information bus: pci@0000:00:08.0
             version: 00
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: msi pm cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             ressources: mémoire:df432000-df432fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             produit: Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 14
             information bus: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 31
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             ressources: irq:126 mémoire:df410000-df41ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                produit: xHCI Host Controller
                fabriquant: Linux 4.8.0-53-generic xhci-hcd
                identifiant matériel: 0
                information bus: usb@1
                nom logique: usb1
                version: 4.08
                fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=16 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Vidéo
                   produit: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
                   fabriquant: 04081-0009480016421002187
                   identifiant matériel: 6
                   information bus: usb@1:6
                   version: 0.03
                   numéro de série: 200901010001
                   fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Interface sans fil Bluetooth
                   fabriquant: Intel Corp.
                   identifiant matériel: 8
                   information bus: usb@1:8
                   version: 0.01
                   fonctionnalités: bluetooth usb-2.01
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Clavier
                   produit: ITE Device(8910)
                   fabriquant: ITE Tech. Inc.
                   identifiant matériel: b
                   information bus: usb@1:b
                   version: 0.03
                   fonctionnalités: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                produit: xHCI Host Controller
                fabriquant: Linux 4.8.0-53-generic xhci-hcd
                identifiant matériel: 1
                information bus: usb@2
                nom logique: usb2
                version: 4.08
                fonctionnalités: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic:1 NON-RÉCLAMÉ
             description: Signal processing controller
             produit: Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 14.2
             information bus: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 31
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             ressources: mémoire:df431000-df431fff
        *-generic:2
             description: Signal processing controller
             produit: Sunrise Point-H LPSS I2C Controller #0
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 15
             information bus: pci@0000:00:15.0
             version: 31
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             ressources: irq:16 mémoire:df430000-df430fff
        *-generic:3
             description: Signal processing controller
             produit: Sunrise Point-H LPSS I2C Controller #1
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 15.1
             information bus: pci@0000:00:15.1
             version: 31
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             ressources: irq:17 mémoire:df42f000-df42ffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             produit: Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 16
             information bus: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 31
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             ressources: irq:322 mémoire:df42e000-df42efff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             produit: Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 17
             information bus: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 31
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 66MHz
             fonctionnalités: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             ressources: irq:319 mémoire:df428000-df429fff mémoire:df42d000-df42d0ff portE/S:f090(taille=8) portE/S:f080(taille=4) portE/S:f060(taille=32) mémoire:df42c000-df42c7ff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             produit: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1c
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             ressources: irq:123 mémoire:df300000-df3fffff
           *-network
                description: Interface réseau sans fil
                produit: Wireless 7265
                fabriquant: Intel Corporation
                identifiant matériel: 0
                information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
                nom logique: wlp2s0
                version: 59
                numéro de série: d0:57:7b:af:71:48
                bits: 64 bits
                horloge: 33MHz
                fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-53-generic firmware=22.361476.0 ip=192.168.1.25 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                ressources: irq:323 mémoire:df300000-df301fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             produit: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1c.3
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: f1
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             ressources: irq:124 portE/S:d000(taille=4096) mémoire:df200000-df2fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                produit: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                fabriquant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                identifiant matériel: 0
                information bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
                nom logique: enp3s0
                version: 15
                numéro de série: 2c:4d:54:25:34:12
                taille: 10Mbit/s
                capacité: 1Gbit/s
                bits: 64 bits
                horloge: 33MHz
                fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                ressources: irq:321 portE/S:d000(taille=256) mémoire:df204000-df204fff mémoire:df200000-df203fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             produit: Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1c.6
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1c.6
             version: f1
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             ressoThank you in advance for your assistanceurces: irq:125 mémoire:df100000-df1fffff
           *-generic
                description: Unassigned class
                produit: RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader
                fabriquant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                identifiant matériel: 0
                information bus: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: 01
                bits: 32 bits
                horloge: 33MHz
                fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                ressources: irq:320 mémoire:df100000-df100fff
        *-generic:4
             description: Signal processing controller
             produit: Sunrise Point-H LPSS UART #0
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1e
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: 31
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             ressources: irq:20 mémoire:df42b000-df42bfff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             produit: Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1f
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 31
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory NON-RÉCLAMÉ
             description: Memory controller
             produit: Sunrise Point-H PMC
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1f.2
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 31
             bits: 32 bits
             horloge: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             configuration: latency=0
             ressources: mémoire:df424000-df427fff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             produit: Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1f.3
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 31
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             fonctionnalités: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             ressources: irq:324 mémoire:df420000-df423fff mémoire:df400000-df40ffff
        *-serial NON-RÉCLAMÉ
             description: SMBus
             produit: Sunrise Point-H SMBus
             fabriquant: Intel Corporation
             identifiant matériel: 1f.4
             information bus: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 31
             bits: 64 bits
             horloge: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             ressources: mémoire:df42a000-df42a0ff portE/S:f040(taille=32)
     *-scsi:0
          identifiant matériel: 1
          nom logique: scsi0
          fonctionnalités: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             produit: HFS256G39TND-N21
             identifiant matériel: 0.0.0
             information bus: scsi@0:0.0.0
             nom logique: /dev/sda
             version: 0P10
             numéro de série: FI6AN01341070A83W
             taille: 238GiB (256GB)
             fonctionnalités: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=f29d9901-e36a-4b98-bb5f-6f191a71e76c logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0
                description: reserved partition
                fabriquant: Windows
                identifiant matériel: 1
                information bus: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                nom logique: /dev/sda1
                numéro de série: 47eeb468-4414-40f7-9e38-a7340fc910dc
                capacité: 15MiB
                fonctionnalités: nofs precious readonly hidden nomount
                configuration: name=Microsoft reserved partition
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                fabriquant: Windows
                identifiant matériel: 2
                information bus: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                nom logique: /dev/sda2
                version: 3.1
                numéro de série: 7ebaaa2c-8fbf-9b4c-95e9-812e0d98184c
                taille: 119GiB
                capacité: 119GiB
                fonctionnalités: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2017-06-04 08:58:28 filesystem=ntfs name=Basic data partition state=clean
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows FAT volume
                fabriquant: MSDOS5.0
                identifiant matériel: 3
                information bus: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                nom logique: /dev/sda3
                version: FAT32
                numéro de série: 708a-8b84
                taille: 2029MiB
                capacité: 2047MiB
                fonctionnalités: fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=BOOT REPAIR name=Basic data partition
     *-scsi:1
          identifiant matériel: 2
          nom logique: scsi1
          fonctionnalités: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             produit: HGST HTS721010A9
             identifiant matériel: 0.0.0
             information bus: scsi@1:0.0.0
             nom logique: /dev/sdb
             version: A3J0
             numéro de série: JR1000D30LNU4E
             taille: 931GiB (1TB)
             fonctionnalités: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=823f2d7d-72ce-4319-a5d7-3bd97c674330 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                fabriquant: mkfs.fat
                identifiant matériel: 1
                information bus: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                nom logique: /dev/sdb1
                nom logique: /boot/efi
                version: FAT32
                numéro de série: 1cfd-d533
                taille: 510MiB
                capacité: 511MiB
                fonctionnalités: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro name=EFI System Partition state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: Volume EXT4
                fabriquant: Linux
                identifiant matériel: 2
                information bus: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
                nom logique: /dev/sdb2
                nom logique: /
                version: 1.0
                numéro de série: d4ff73de-ab17-4ec6-9086-0cca1e69e013
                taille: 915GiB
                fonctionnalités: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2017-06-04 19:44:19 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2017-06-06 17:22:58 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2017-06-06 17:23:38 state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: Linux swap volume
                fabriquant: Linux
                identifiant matériel: 3
                information bus: scsi@1:0.0.0,3
                nom logique: /dev/sdb3
                version: 1
                numéro de série: 4ff08b50-6f60-42a9-8949-46ae5e545eeb
                taille: 15GiB
                capacité: 15GiB
                fonctionnalités: nofs swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
     *-scsi:2
          identifiant matériel: 3
          nom logique: scsi2
          fonctionnalités: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             produit: DVD A  DA8AESH
             fabriquant: Slimtype
             identifiant matériel: 0.0.0
             information bus: scsi@2:0.0.0
             nom logique: /dev/cdrom
             nom logique: /dev/cdrw
             nom logique: /dev/dvd
             nom logique: /dev/dvdrw
             nom logique: /dev/sr0
             version: XAA1
             fonctionnalités: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
  *-power NON-RÉCLAMÉ
       description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       produit: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       fabriquant: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       identifiant matériel: 1
       version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       numéro de série: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       capacité: 32768mWh
```

The problem is that the EFI is mounted on /dev/sdb ?

Does anyone have a solution ?

Thank you in advance for your assistance...

Greats

Comment: Do you by any chance have SecureBoot enabled? If that option is enabled on my computer, dual-booting is messed up as well. Try to search in BIOS and see if that option is enabled and try disabling it.

Comment: Looks like a video problem, with your Nvidia hardware.  Did you try the "nomodeset" on the kernel line?  Lots of solutions for Nvidia boot problems.

Comment: Boot-Repairs lspci and lshw only show the Skylake video. Did you turn off nVidia in UEFI? It should just boot with Skylake but there is an Intel update to the Skylake driver, not sure if yet in Ubuntu. But you are not showing standard OEM Windows install?? You do not even have an ESP - efi system partition on sda. Did you swap drives in SATA ports? And grub normally only installs to ESP on sda which you do not have? And you have a Windows entry in UEFI Boot0000 that boots grub. see `sudo efibootmgr -v`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by installing the proprietary Nvidia Driver...

As mentioned in Chapter 2 of this post:

[Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics)

Finally,The fact that the EFI is installed on dev/sdb and not on dev/sdba does not seem to be a problem...

Now, Ubuntu 16.04, great thanks for your help and long live to the Ubuntu community !